# Binary handling for 3d printing js-slicer (SLAcer.js)

Tags: javascript, file, binary, slicers, 3d-printing

**Introduction**

Hey folks,
i am currently working on a JavaScript-based 3d slicing tool (SLAcer.js - awesome work btw.), that can generate convenient print files for my cheap dlp-printer (SparkMaker).
The printing files consist of some G-Code and simple binary layers/images (see [here](https://github.com/bastirichter/Sparkmaker/blob/master/file_format.md)).

I am already able to generate the G-Code and a Uint8Array that contains the relevant information of the binary layer.
All G-Code and binary layers currently get concatenated as a String (there may be the first Problem) and in the end can be downloaded as print file (.wow) as part of a zip File. (projects default JSZip Framework) (see [here](https://n0sr3v.github.io/SLAcer.js/))

The point where i am struggling is:

**I am not able to get the right TextEncoding for the binary layer to match the original binary layer.**

```
var array = new Uint8Array(width*height/8);
var binary_layer;
```

Already tried several things, including:

```
binary_layer=(new TextDecoder("utf-8")).decode(array) /*with different text encodes*/
```

Also tried:

```
binary_layer=bin2string(array)
function bin2string(array){
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
result+= (String.fromCharCode(array[i]));
}
console.log(result);
return result;
}
```

What amazes me is that, when exporting each Uint8Array as a separate binary txt file they nearly perfectly match the wanted/original pattern

Concatenation:

```
file_contents = "[some gecode]";
file_contents += binary_layer;
```

**Summary**

```
var staring = "hello";
var array = new Uint8Array(2);
array[0]=255;
array[1]=0;
```

**Wanted file contents** (both text and raw binary - utf8):

```
hello(xFF)(NUL)
```

This may sound easy, but in terms of right encoding it's not:

- [file sliced by SLAcer (binary layers differ)](https://n0sr3v.github.io/SLAcer.js/other/self_sliced_print.wow)
- [single layer file (does nearly match the original first layer pattern)](https://n0sr3v.github.io/SLAcer.js/other/slices/1.txt)
- [file sliced by original software](https://n0sr3v.github.io/SLAcer.js/other/print.wow)
  Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue could be fixed (still further testing is needed)

Problem could be solved by saving all data with `{binary: true}` option and using simple hex to string decoder method:

```
function bin2string(array){
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
result+= (String.fromCharCode(array[i]));
}
return result;
}
```

Annoyingly (in my case):

```
var array = new Uint8Array(2);
array[1]=255;
(new TextDecoder("utf-8")).decode(array)
```

Did output: `(NUL)(xFD)`

But should have output: `(NUL)(xFF)`

This need to be discussed further more! (see also [here](https://github.com/n0sr3v/SLAcer.js/issues/1))