# Problems with TextDecoder decoding Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, hex, byte, uint8array, text-decoding

Having problems with TextDecoder decoding Uint8Array. ([background info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073758/binary-handling-for-3d-printing-js-slicer-slacer-js))

```
var staring = "hello";
var array = new Uint8Array(2);
array[0]=255;
array[1]=0;
var binary=(new TextDecoder("utf-8")).decode(array)
console.log(binary);
```

Should give me: `hello\xFF\x00`

But instead gives me: `hello\xFD\x00`

Am i doing something wrong?